# Why does admin_body_class not work?

Tags: filters, user-roles, body-class

I'm trying to add the body class of the current user role to both the frontend and the admin backend.

Why does `admin_body_class` not work for admin?

The comment to this question does not work: [How to insert the current user's role into the body class in the admin backend](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/399134/how-to-insert-the-current-users-role-into-the-body-class-in-the-admin-backend)

This works for the front end in the theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter("body_class", function($classes) {
    global $current_user;
    foreach ($current_user->roles as $user_role) {
        $classes[] = "role-{$user_role}";
    }
    return $classes;
});
```

This does not work for the backend in the theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter("admin_body_class", function($classes) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  foreach ($user->roles as $user_role) {
    $classes .= " role-{$user_role}";
  }
  return $classes;
});
```

Comment: where is your code located? when does it run? When this runs is significant it can't be put anywhere.

Comment: You have no priority param on your filter, so technically the `admin_body_class` filter could be fired again after yours, and your changes could be overwritten. I can't say if this is the case, but I'd try adding a high priority value.

Comment: @vancoder  Thanks! What priority would I use for admin?

Comment: @TomJNowell  Thanks! They are in the theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Try a high priority first (eg 99) and see if it helps.

Comment: @vancoder Ok, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the admin backend; I needed to restructure the filter to be able to add a priority:

```
function add_admin_body_class($classes) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
foreach ($user->roles as $user_role) {
    $classes .= " role-{$user_role}";
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter("admin_body_class", "add_admin_body_class", 9999);
```

Comment: Actually you could have just added the priority at the end of your original anonymous function: `}, 9999 );`